# WSO2 Streaming Integrator - Siddhi.io Aggregate multiple events into one event

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I have a requirement to collect multiple events into a single one and consider it as a single event. The output stream should include the input events as a list.

Basically, when the following events are passed

```
{InvoiceNumber:1, LineItem: 1, Value: 100}
{InvoiceNumber:1, LineItem: 2, Value: 200}
{InvoiceNumber:1, LineItem: 3, Value: 300}
```

I need the output to be like the following

```
[InvoiceNumber:1, lineItems: [{LineItem: 1, Value: 100}, {LineItem: 2, Value: 200}, {LineItem: 3, Value: 300}]
```

How do I achieve this with WSO2 Streaming Integrator? Or Siddhi.io.

I attempted the following but it still inserting each stream into the output stream

```
partition with (InvoiceNo of CSVInputStream)
begin

    from every e1=CSVInputStream
        within 1 min
    select e1.InvoiceNo, list:collect(e1.LineItem) as lineItems
    group by e1.InvoiceNo
    insert into AggregatedStream;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use partitions, as this is a simple use case, try windows. Time batch windows in your case, https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/api/latest/#timebatch-window

```
from CSVInputStream#window.timeBatch(1 min)
select e1.InvoiceNo, list:collect(e1.LineItem) as lineItems
group by e1.InvoiceNo
insert into AggregatedStream;
```